# Generating authorized IDs

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I am looking for a way to generate IDs (a sequence of bytes) which I can (in some way) verify to be generated by my application.

I am currently using AES-GCM for this purpose which encrypts some random input. When receiving these AES-GCM IDs I am trying to decrypt them, if it fails I know it wasn't generated by me. But having a static encryption key that will probably never change in the future (as I would have to redistribute all generated IDs) is (as I understand it) a problem with GCM as it gets less secure whenever a nonce is reused which is bound to happen at some point.

Another approach I have in mind would be to generate a pair of `(plain_text_id,hmac(plain_text_id, secret))` as the `plain_text_id` is some random generated id which I internally map to a real user id (it's thus useless to an attacker). This is the same as signing some plain-text.

I do not want to check against a database as I explicitly want to employ this sanity check before hitting the database (so that e.g. a random attacker cannot DDoS me with random id's)

Is there another approach for generating verifiable id's? Is using AES-XXX or a HMAC approach (like outlined above) sufficient? And if so: which one and why?

Comment: this sounds a lot like [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/), might be worth seeing how they handle this

Comment: Was thinking about JWT too but just wanted to make sure I am doing this right. Thanks! HMAC seems like the best approach here